# Extend Sublime Text 3 build options

Tags: makefile, sublimetext3

I am working with the AVR package in Sublime Text 3. If I CMD-SHIFT-B (Build With) I get options Make and Make - Clean.

I would like to add options to execute additional sections in the Make file. Specifically, I'd like to have an option Make - Avrdude to run avrdude to program the Atmel. I am able to do this from the command line, but not from Sublime.

How do I add to the Build With options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build systems in Sublime are defined via `sublime-build` files, which are JSON formatted files that tell it how to carry out the build. These include at least one option for the base build and can include 0 or more "variants" that slightly modify the command.

The build system that is used to invoke `make` is called `Make.sublime-build` and is in the `Makefile` package. The easiest way to see the contents of that file are with [PackageResourceViewer](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer).

By default, it looks like this (as of Sublime Build 3126):

```json
{
    "shell_cmd": "make",
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:\n]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "working_dir": "${folder:${project_path:${file_path}}}",
    "selector": "source.makefile",
    "syntax": "Packages/Makefile/Make Output.sublime-syntax",
    "keyfiles": ["Makefile", "makefile"],

    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Clean",
            "shell_cmd": "make clean"
        }
    ]
}
```

The main body supplies the `shell_cmd` to invoke `make` along with all of the other build options needed, and the `variants` section allows you to override some of those settings to do something different. Anything you don't override in the variant uses the base settings.

In order to add in extra variants you just need to add them to that variants array with a distinct name and the command to use. As an example, my variant section looks like this:

```json
"variants":
[
    {
        "name": "Clean",
        "shell_cmd": "make clean"
    },
    {
        "name": "Run",
        "shell_cmd": "make run"
    }
]
```

---

### Important Note: The file is JSON formatted, and if your formatting is wrong (and thus Sublime cannot parse the file) no error message is generated, and the file will be ignored.

One way to go about this is to override the default file. To do using PackageResourceViewer, select `PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource` from the command palette (`Tools > Command Palette` or the associated key for your platform), select `Makefile` and then `Make.sublime-build`.

That will open the file, allowing you to modify it. When you save it, your saved file will override the built in version, which means that however you're accessing the build now, it will work the same way and your new option will appear. This does however mask any official changes to the build file (e.g. if a future build of Sublime modifies this file).

You can also do something similar to the above, only instead of saving the file, use `Save As` and save it into your `User` package instead. If you go this route, you need to manually select your build from the `Tools > Build System` menu to use it. Note that the name that you give the file controls the name that appears in the menu, so if you give it the same name as the default, the same name will show up twice in that menu.

A third option would be to store the build settings directly inside your `sublime-project` file (if you're using one), in which case the custom build is available only inside of that project. In this case you still need to manually select the build.